# 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I created an update form, the form has 2 time field and 2 date time field, once click on submit even nothing change, I got an error "'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'strip'".
but there is no error when creating a new object for the same model .
modles:

```
time_start=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
htime_start=models.TimeField(blank=True,null=True)
time_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
htime_end=models.TimeField(blank=True,null=True)
time_require=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
machine=models.ForeignKey(Machine,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)
```

forms:

```
class AssignTimeForProjects(forms.ModelForm):
title = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
owner=forms.CharField(disabled=True)
time_require=forms.TimeField(disabled=True)
class Meta:
    model = tb_order
    # fields='__all__'
    fields = ['title', 'owner', 'grade', 'quantity',
              'time_require','htime_start','color',
              'mould','time_start','time_end', 'htime_end' ,'machine']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AssignTimeForProjects, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["time_end"] = JalaliDateField(label=('تاریخ اتمام'), widget=(AdminJalaliDateWidget))
    self.fields["time_start"] = JalaliDateField(label=('تاریخ شروع'), widget=(AdminJalaliDateWidget))
```

Html:

```
<label>{{ form.htime_start.label}}</label>
                {% render_field form.htime_start  type="time"  class+="form-control timepicker" autocomplete="off" %}
                <br>
                <label>{{ form.time_end.label}}</label>
                {% render_field form.time_end  class+="form-control" autocomplete="off" %}
                <br>
                <label>{{ form.htime_end.label}}</label>
                {% render_field form.htime_end  type="time"  class+="form-control" autocomplete="off" %}
```

Comment: Share error trace

Comment: '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/Desktop/alvand/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']

Comment: This is not error trace. This is a path to a file that has a code that failed. If you are copying that from browser then below there should be a list of methods called

Comment: here is from views.py:error occurred when call form.is_valid() function :  newproject=tb_order.objects.all()
    p=newproject.get(id=pk)
    form=AssignTimeForProjects(instance=p)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=AssignTimeForProjects(request.POST,instance=p)
        if form.is_valid(): …
           form.save()
           messages.success(request, 'timeset was updated successfully')
        return redirect('p-mainpage')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "pline/settime.html", context)

Comment: this is from forms.py :        """Return an ErrorDict for the data provided for the form."""
        if self._errors is None:
            self.full_clean()
        return self._errors
    def is_valid(self):
        """Return True if the form has no errors, or False otherwise."""
        return self.is_bound and not self.errors …
    def add_prefix(self, field_name):
        """
        Return the field name with a prefix appended, if this Form has a
        prefix set.